# Get the other element from pair

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How to get one element from the pair (list of 2 elements) in Python 3, if I know another element? For example, in the turn-based strategy game, I want to swap players:

```
players = [playerA, playerB]
active_player = playerA

players_tmp = list(players) 
players_tmp.remove(active_player)
active_player = players_tmp[0]
```

This code works perfectly, but it's ugly.

Of course, in this particular case, I can always store an index (0 or 1) of the active player, and then do:

```
self._active_player = 1 - self._active_player
```

And then write the @property method. But it's not that interesting.

Is there any beautiful way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set;

```
players = {playerA, playerB}
active_player = {playerA}

active_player = players - active_player
```

or;

```
players = {playerA, playerB}
active_player = playerA

active_player = (players - {active_player}).pop()
```

Comment: Your solution looks nice. Since active_player is a set of one object, the only problem I see is to retrieve the active_player from the set (without destroying it).

Comment: @splattru `tuple(active_player)[0]`

Comment: @splattru or `next(iter(active_player))`

Answer (score 4):

For the task of finding the other element in a pair, I’d just write a nice and clear function:

```
def other_of(pair, item):
    a, b = pair
    return a if item == b else b
…
active_player = other_of(players, active_player)
```

If it works for your case, though, [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) might be a better way to cycle through options:

```
import itertools

player_rotation = itertools.cycle(players)
…
active_player = next(player_rotation)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the fact that `True` can be used as index 1

```
>>> l = ['a','b']
>>> l['a' is l[0]]
'b'
>>> l['b' is l[0]]
'a'
```

So you can define your function as

```
def find(l,i):
    return l[i is l[0]]
```

Demo

```
>>> find(["Player1","Player2"],"Player1")
'Player2'
>>> find(["Player1","Player2"],"Player2")
'Player1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just swap when you want to change the player and take the first element then you don't have to care who is active as you will get a different player each time:

```
players = ["playerA", "playerB"]

players[0],players[1] = players[1],players[0]

active = players[0]
```

Or better again as minitech commented just call `list.reverse`

```
  players = ["playerA", "playerB"]
  players.reverse()
  active = players[0]
  print(active)
  playerB
```

Comment: `list.reverse` is in-place.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common way to toggle a flag:

```
if active_player == playerA:
    active_player = playerB
else:
    active_player = playerA
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The question just wants to reassign the `active_player`.

Answer (score 0):

a better solution for this would be to have a generator.

```
players = ['sdf','asdf','sasd']
active = 'sdf'
temp_players = (player for player in players if player != active)
active = temp_players.next()
```

this way you can have list of all your players and get one player everytime to replace with. 
it will also be better a easier if you are gonna have multiple players in a team playing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
players = ['playerA', 'playerB']
def active_player(): return players[0]
print(active_player()) 
players.reverse()
print(active_player())
```

that gives :

```
playerA
playerB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# conditional expressions
active_player = players[0] if players[1] == active_player else players[1]

# negative index
active_player = players[players.index(active_player) - 1]
```