# Get the other element from a set (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, set

Let's say there is a method, `get_method`, that the caller needs to pass an optional argument, `opt_arg`.

```
def get_method(opt_arg):
    if opt_arg in args_set:
        # do stuff with opt_arg
    elif opt_arg is None:
        other_arg = get_other_arg()
        # do stuff with other_arg
```

The values of `opt_arg` are strictly within a set:

```
args_set = { "foo", "bar" }
```

I want to create a method to return the **other** `opt_arg` from the `opt_args_set`, as in *other than the one used last time*.

The idea is that multiple callers of the `get_method` may be calling it at the same time and would like to provide some basic load balancing.

I thought of doing this:

```
def get_other_arg(previous_used_arg=''):
    elem = next(iter())
    if elem != previous_used_arg:
        return elem
    else:
        return next(iter())
```

I have also seen this interesting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30879753/6003691) which looks much better.

Any input/feedback on whether my approach or the one in the answer link above is better will be great to help me understand Python sets.

Comment: I think you have the beginning of two questions here. The first is the one you asked, about Python sets, and the second is about your use of sets for keeping track of state in a function with multiple callers. My answer addresses the first, and I recommend changing the title of the question (or asking a new one) if you want more answers about the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer addresses the particular question of how to access one element of a (two-element) set, given the other element.

---

If you're using a set, you can use the [set difference operator](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference), then your method of choice to get the sole element of a set (the first bit is identical to the answer you linked):

```
options = {'a', 'b'}
other = options - {'a'} # b is {'b'}

# A few ways to get the sole element of a set
b = next(iter(other))
b = min(other) # or max
b, = other # or "[b] = other"
```

The last method for extracting the sole element of a set also raises an exception if the set has multiple elements.

If you don't mind destroying the list of possible values (i.e. if you already are using a copy), you can `remove` or `discard`<sup>1</sup> the value you don't want, then `pop` the remaining value.

```
options = {'a', 'b'}
options.remove('a')
value = options.pop()
# options is now empty, and value is 'b'
```

In general, to understand sets, I'd start by reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

---

<sup>1</sup> `remove` raises an exception if the element is missing; `discard` does not